# Is there any bughouse android app?

Tags: online-chess, online, websites, bughouse

I want to play bughouse with my friend against other players, is there any android app that lets me team up with my friend and play bughouse?

preferably at our own pace, not the the fast bughouse that is played in tournaments, because we live in different timezones, he lives in australia, me in +3 GMT, and we have work so the probability of the two of us being online at the same time is so low

Comment: Excellent question. Not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

There exists "Yafi", which use FICS chess server, where you can play bughouse :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.mg6.yafi

Answer (score 1):

We working on it. See doublechess server project in czech open bics article.
http://bughousechess.wz.cz/BICS/CzechOpen/
or in http://bughousechess.wz.cz/BICS/index.html
there is link.
Its based on nodejs + chat + javascript. So far working ok from mobile or PC, any time for game and move clockssettings first beta. It is possible to run it over win or linux.
There is now all time server running more or less. You welcome help us test,u can play on both boards also vs your friend or anybody. Now in test phase.
PS. in yafi u cannot see and use pieces in hand easy. Dont mention u cannot play slower bughouse, only fast one. in bics and also in this dcb u can play delay=bronstein time for move control ie slower bughouse chess from any web browser even smartphone.

Answer (score 1):

Android mobile app for bughouse online game with your friends: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.mail.park.bughouse

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you are looking for, but I'd like to throw this out there for anyone looking for a Bughouse app that lets you play both boards on one device. It's far more suitable for tablets and other large devices, but definitely still playable on phones. Currently there is no support for using/connecting multiple devices, but this app is intended for groups of people who just want to use one device for all the boards.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fhu.bughousechess